# Updating Grid rows from other grid rows in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have a Grid view that displays various records. From a FieldUpdated event in one row I might Update a value in other dependant rows also displayed in the Grid view.

Changes in the Row whose field triggered the postback are shown immediately when the postback returns. However, how can I indicate the other dependant rows that have also been updated that need to be refreshed in the client?

`sender.SetValueExt<DAC.field>(dependantRow, newValue);`
works to set the values and trigger the related events but it does not cause an update in the UI until the Cache is Persisted and the entire UI is refreshed.

Comment: how about if you use field updating or verifying event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for

```
RecordsView.View.RequestRefresh();
```