# Update field for all rows on grid

Tags: acumatica

I am working on recalculating percentage value of each rows when a field value on a row is updated. I have created two custom fields PoundsUsed and PercentOfWIP for INComponentTran DAC. When PoundsUsed is updated I would like to recalculate the PercentOfWIP for all INComponentTran records in Kit Assembly.

I have also created a custom field that is the sum of INComponentTran's PoundsUsed and calculating percentage based on that. Below is the code snippet that I have written to accomplish but it's only updating the latest record.

```
private decimal CalculateTotalLBSProduced()
        {
            decimal totalPortions = 0M;
            decimal totalLBs = 0M;
            foreach (INComponentTran tran in Base.Components.Select())
            {
                INTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<INTranExt>();
                if (tranExt.UsrPoundsUsed.HasValue)
                {
                    if (tran.UOM == "PRTION")
                    {
                        totalPortions = totalPortions + tranExt.UsrPoundsUsed.Value;
                    }
                    if (tran.UOM == "LB")
                    {
                        totalLBs = totalLBs + tranExt.UsrPoundsUsed.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            return totalPortions - totalLBs;
        }

        private void CalculatePercentOfWIP()
        {
            decimal totalLBSProduced = CalculateTotalLBSProduced();
            Base.Document.Cache.SetValueExt<INKitRegisterExt.usrLBSProduced>(Base.Document.Current, totalLBSProduced);
            foreach (INComponentTran tran in Base.Components.Select())
            {
                decimal percentOfWIP = 0M;
                Base.Components.Current = tran;
                INTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<INTranExt>();
                if (tran.UOM == "PRTION")
                {
                    decimal? poundsUsed = tran.GetExtension<INTranExt>().UsrPoundsUsed.GetValueOrDefault();
                    if (totalLBSProduced != 0 && poundsUsed.HasValue && poundsUsed.Value !=0)
                    {
                        percentOfWIP = (poundsUsed.Value / totalLBSProduced) * 100;
                    }
                }
                Base.Components.Cache.SetValueExt<INTranExt.usrPercentOfWIP>(tran, percentOfWIP);
            }
        }




    protected void INComponentTran_UsrPoundsUsed_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        var row = (INComponentTran)e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;
        CalculateTotalLBSProduced();
        CalculatePercentOfWIP();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding ``Base.Components.Cache.Update(tran);`` after the ``SetValueExt`` and also perhaps a ``Base.Actions.PressSave();``

Comment: You also could possibly use DAC property attributes such as ``PXDBScalar`` or ``PXFormula`` to accomplish this automatically. I haven't taken the time to determine if that would be a good fit.

Comment: Thanks @Deetz. I have had tried Update before as well which freezes as it caused infinite loop of event occurrence. I think even using PXFormula I get to update the field on row level only. I was thinking that I would use PXAction for this. Not sure if it's an ideal solution but this is simpler to execute.

Comment: If you move the ``SetValueExt`` to the Event Handler and use ``RowUpdating`` instead, you don't need the ``.Update()`` or ``.Save()``. You can just set the value and let it continue updating.

Comment: @Deetz I found the perfect solution. :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555366/updating-grid-rows-from-other-grid-rows-in-acumatica
Not sure if I put the question in right way but this was something that I was looking for.